# No provider for UrlHelperService

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3

I am just running through an example of how to build an ionic app. When I serve the app however I get this error,

```ts
Error: No provider for UrlHelperService!
at injectionError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1527:90)
at noProviderError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1565:12)
at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:3007:19)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:3046:25)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:2978:25)
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:2847:21)
at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:9847:25)
at _createClass (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:9898:32)
at _createProviderInstance$1 (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:9858:26)
at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:9843:17)
```

my app.module.ts

```ts
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import {LoginPage} from "../pages/login/login";
import {OAuthService} from "angular-oauth2-oidc";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
AboutPage,
ContactPage,
HomePage,
TabsPage,
LoginPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
AboutPage,
ContactPage,
HomePage,
TabsPage,
LoginPage  ],
      providers: [
    OAuthService,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

my app.component.ts

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: 
SplashScreen, oauthService: OAuthService) {
    if (oauthService.hasValidIdToken()) {
      this.rootPage = TabsPage;
    } else {
      this.rootPage = LoginPage;
    }
    platform.ready().then(() => {

  statusBar.styleDefault();
  splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

I am using 
Ionic Framework: 3.7.0
Ionic App Scripts: 3.0.0
Angular Core: 4.4.3
Angular Compiler CLI: 4.4.3
Node: 6.11.0
OS Platform: Windows 10
Navigator Platform: Win32

Comment: When using a service, an `@ngModule` must import {...} from '...' then list it under `providers: [ ... ]`

Comment: Where is your UrlHelperService ?

Comment: @Melchia the UrlHelperService is included in the OAuthService I thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error shows up when you are using some service (In your case `UrlHelperService`) in your application but you haven't added it to `providers`.

Make sure when you create and use any services in your application you MUST import them in `providers` in **@NgModule**

```
import { SomeService } from "../services/some-service.service";

@NgModule({
        declarations: [ // Components ],
        imports: [ // Modules ],
        bootstrap: [IonicApp],
        entryComponents: [// Entry Components],
        providers: [ SomeService ] // <==== HERE
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 3):

To Fix this,

In app.module.ts add UrlHelperService to be imported from *angular-oauth2-oidc*

```
import {OAuthService, UrlHelperService} from "angular-oauth2-oidc";
```

In Provider array in the same file (app.module.ts), add UrlHelperService

```
providers: [
    OAuthService,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    UrlHelperService,
    OAuthService,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
```

Answer (score 3):

As per sample [application](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/okta-sample), I found this. Please add:

```
import { OAuthModule } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
```

Add `OAuthModule.forRoot()` to imports inside `app.module.ts` file.